# How do I format JSON Date String with Swift?

Tags: json, swift, nsdateformatter

I make an http get request to a server and get back a json object with a date string like this:

```
{
    name = "Place1";
    temperature = 79;
    humidity = 68;
    reported_at = "2013-07-21T19:32:00Z";
}
```

I want to format the reported_at key so I can display a readable date and time to the user.

This is the swift code I am trying which keeps returning nil, as it cannot format the date.

```
    var str = "2013-07-21T19:32:00Z"

    var dateFor: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS"

    var yourDate: NSDate? = dateFor.dateFromString(str)

    println(yourDate)
```

How can I format this date and time with Swift correctly? I want to display the date and time to the user so they can know when the reading was taken.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the following string format to convert a server string into a Date

```
dateFor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: DO NOT quote the `Z`. That will give the wrong result.

Comment: @rmaddy just tried it and not quoting 'Z' is giving me a wrong

Comment: @zellb I can assure you that quoting the `Z` will give the wrong result. If you think you get the wrong result when you don't quote the `Z` then you are doing something else incorrectly or misunderstanding the result.

Comment: @rmaddy  On my playground `var str = "2015-02-27T11:24:00Z"
var dateFor: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
var yourDate: NSDate? = dateFor.dateFromString(str)` is giving me {Some "Feb 27, 2015, 12:24 PM"} while with quote Z is giving {Some "Feb 27, 2015, 11:24 AM"} which is correct based on my string

Comment: The date `2015-02-27T11:24:00Z` is at 11:24am in GMT time (that's what the `Z` means in the date string). You must live in the GMT+1 timezone. Correct? If you don't quote the `Z`, the date string is properly interpreted in GMT time. If you do quote the `Z`, the date string is incorrectly interpreted in local time.

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" should be the correct date format

Comment: no matter what I do... always nil. what swift was working v1 or v2?

Comment: @user1019042 this answer was for swift 1.2 but still can you post your string date ?

Answer (score 34):

Nowadays (September 2017) in Swift 4 there are smarter ways to decode ISO8601:

- `ISO8601DateFormatter`

  ```
  let str = "2013-07-21T19:32:00Z"
  let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
  let yourDate = formatter.date(from: str)
  ```
- `JSONDecoder`

  ```
  struct Place : Decodable {

      let name : String
      let temperature : Int
      let humidity : Int
      let reportedAt : Date

  }

  let json = """
  {"name" : "Place1", "temperature" : 79, "humidity" : 68, "reported_at" : "2013-07-21T19:32:00Z"}
  """
  let data = Data(json.utf8)

  let decoder =  JSONDecoder()
  decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
  decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
  let place = try! decoder.decode(Place.self, from: data)
  ```

Comment: Available in ios 10 and up

Comment: Great answer. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) (you probably should!) simply use:

Serialize:

```
let date:NSDate = ....
let dateInRegion = DateInRegion( absoluteTime: date )
let serializedString:String = dateInRegin.toString( .ISO8601Format( .Full ))!
```

Deserialize:

```
let serializedDate:String = "2016-03-01T22:10:55.200Z"
let date:NSDate? = serializedDate.toDateFromISO8601()
```

Comment: SwiftDate can be found at this link: https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer using `extension` in `Swift4`.

```
extension String {
  func toDate(dateFormat: String) -> Date? {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat

    let date: Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: self)
    return date
}
```

Simple Usage

```
let str = "2013-07-21T19:32:00Z";
let dateStr = str.toDate(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```

Also, Check dateFormat that you want from here. [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

Comment: In Swift 4 I'd prefer `ISO8601DateFormatter` or decode the JSON directly with `JSONDecoder`

Comment: @vad Yes, Using `JSONDecoder` will be better. But, `ISO8601DateFormatter`, it does not support milliseconds. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847672/iso8601dateformatter-doesnt-parse-iso-date-string

Comment: There are no milliseconds in the question and in macOS 10.13 / iOS 11 milliseconds are supported.

Answer (score 0):

For Converting `JSON` String to Date & Time in `Swift 3.0` Use Below Code:-

```
    let timeinterval : TimeInterval = (checkInTime as! NSString).doubleValue
    let dateFromServer = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:timeinterval)
    print(dateFromServer)
    let dateFormater : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    //dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm a"  // 22-Sep-2017 14:53 PM
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"   // 22-Sep-2017 02:53 PM
    print(dateFormater.string(from: dateFromServer as Date))
```

where `checkInTime`will be your String.Hope it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5 you can do something like this (This is a variation of vadian's answer) in case you have a custom date string that is not in 'iso8601':

```
struct Place : Decodable {

    let name : String
    let temperature : Int
    let humidity : Int
    let reportedAt : Date

}

let json = """
{"name" : "Place1", "temperature" : 79, "humidity" : 68, "reported_at" : "2021-05-02 06:00"}
"""
let data = Data(json.utf8)

//FORMAT DATE
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
//Force dateFormatter to be always 24h
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("HH:mm a")
dateFormatter.amSymbol = ""
dateFormatter.pmSymbol = ""
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

let decoder =  JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let place = try! decoder.decode(Place.self, from: data)
```