# I get nil when using NSDateFormatter in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

This is my code :

```
println(myStringDate)    // 2015-02-26T17:46:34.000Z
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ"
let myDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(myStringDate)
println(myDate)        // nil
```

Why nil ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Pretty much everything.  Study closely http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: A working solution was posted only one hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748162/how-do-i-format-json-date-string-in-xcode-with-swift.

Comment: Actually just one thing, as explained by Christian. It worked.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is how you set the date format. Because there is a `T` in your string, you need to "escape" it and say, that it shouldn't affect the formatting of the date.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Also as you see, I've changed the `sss` to `SSS` which stands for miliseconds and also changed the year `YYYY` to lowercase `yyyy` also the same with the `DD`. You have to be really carefully, when to use upper and lowercase letters in your Dateformat-strings.

Check [@HotLicks link in the comments](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) which shows a great overview of the dateformat usage.

Comment: There are still some errors in the date format, compare for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748162/how-do-i-format-json-date-string-in-xcode-with-swift.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that Y is for YearOfWeek

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Done. A bit more general. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Christian Not general at all. If you use it It would look like it is working but it could result in a different date with older dates. If used with today's date  it wouldn't probably be a problem.

Comment: DO NOT quote the `Z` in the format string. That is the timezone specifier. If you quote that then the date/time string will be treated as local time instead of Zulu time. That's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's to late, but

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'"
```

should be

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

because,

1)

```
ss - seconds
SSS - fractional second

sss != SSS
```

2)

```
  T -> 'T'; S -> 'S'
```

And [nice tutorial](http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/)