# DateFormatter returns nil for some strings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm converting date strings from a JSON file to Date format and most the time it works, but this example fails and I can't figure out why. Any ideas appreciated! Thank you.

```
    let input = "2015-06-20T00:47:00.484Z"
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    
    print("ConvertedOutput: \(dateFormatter.date(from: input))")
```

Comment: It's not `sss`, it's `SSS`, it's fractional seconds, not second. Because `484` translated into seconds, that fail.

Comment: If `s` is seconds, how could `s` also be fractional seconds?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I get nil when using NSDateFormatter in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750048/i-get-nil-when-using-nsdateformatter-in-swift) It's not the only "sss" vs "SSS" on that quesiton, but that issue is also present...

Comment: Whoops! Thank you! dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For milliseconds, you should use `SSS` instead of `sss` like this -

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Comment: I'll leave this downvoted to show what kind of stupidity you have to expect - but the answer is exactly the correct one. See https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/

Comment: FlatDog, I strongly recommend you accept this answer because it is the correct one. Lowercase s for seconds, uppercase S for fractional seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Your input is a date string which corresponds to ISO8601 standard. For such date strings, the Foundation has a [ISO8601DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter) class which helps you avoid many edge cases which can lead to wrong date parsing and that's why it's suggested by Apple to use for such date strings this dedicated class than using DateFormatter.

**Code with ISO8601DateFormatter**

```
let dateFormatterIso = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatterIso.formatOptions = [.withFullDate, .withFullTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
let inputDate = dateFormatterIso.date(from: input)
```

**Code with DateFormatter**

If you can't use ISO8601DateFormatter then
you have to correct the date format which has wrong mask for fractional seconds: .SSS instead .sss

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Both formatters returns:

```
▿ Optional<Date>
  ▿ some : 2015-06-20 00:47:00 +0000
    - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 456454020.48399997
```