# Swift: parsing Date from JSON

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, dateformatter, jsondecoder

i working on project where i have to receive data from php server. Everything works good, only two things:
1.) can't parse Date. I know that this question was answered here, but not one of the variants is working in my case. Here is my code

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON


func getClientDataFromServer(id: String?) {
    guard let id = id else {return}
    let jsonUrlString = "https://sverlim.software/cms/clientReadOneClient.php?client_id=10"
    let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString)!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard err == nil else {
            print(err!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        print(response as Any)
        guard let data = data else {return}
        let dateFormatterWithTime: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
        }()

        let datastring = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("data====\(datastring!)")
        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]
        print(json[0]["datarteg"] as Any)
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()

            let object = try! JSON(data: data)
            print(object[0]["datareg"].dateTime)
            print(object[0]["company"].stringValue)

            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatterWithTime)
            let clients = try decoder.decode([Client].self, from: data)
            print(clients)
            let client = clients.first
            print(client!)
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print(jsonErr)
        }
        }.resume()
}
struct Client: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String?
    let phone: String?
    let company: String?
    let discount: String?
    var datareg: Date?
}

class Formatter {
    static let jsonDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()

    static let jsonDateTimeFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss"
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension JSON {

    public var date: Date? {
        get {
            switch self.type {
            case .string:
                return Formatter.jsonDateFormatter.date(from: self.object as! String)
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    public var dateTime: Date? {
        get {
            switch self.type {
            case .string:
                return Formatter.jsonDateTimeFormatter.date(from: self.object as! String)
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }
}
```

i followed this answers

[Swift's JSONDecoder with multiple date formats in a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682626/swifts-jsondecoder-with-multiple-date-formats-in-a-json-string)

[How do I format JSON Date String with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748162/how-do-i-format-json-date-string-with-swift)

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-codable-with-custom-dates/

here is what i'm printing from log

```
data====
 [{"id":"10","name":"\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0435\u0446 
 \u0410\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0440","phone":"+38098497
 4673","company":"2","discount":"0","datereg":"2017-11-28 14:16:16"}]
 nil
 nil
 2
 [SashaApp.Client(id: Optional("10"), name: Optional("Украинец Александр"), 
 phone: Optional("+380984974673"), company: Optional("2"), discount: 
 Optional("0"), datareg: nil)]
 Client(id: Optional("10"), name: Optional("Украинец Александр"), phone: 
 Optional("+380984974673"), company: Optional("2"), discount: 
 Optional("0"), datareg: nil)
```

As we can see the data contains "datareg" field, but after parsing regardless the way(JSONDecoder,JSONSerialization,SwiftyJSON) i receive nil
2) SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6)

Guys will be appreciate for any help. Thank's))

Comment: what happens with your code? print out the date string before parsing it, and include it here, so we can confirm that you are using correct format

Comment: I printed it because i wanted to see the data i receive from server.

Comment: ok, can you share it?

Comment: @AntonZhevchenko show an example of date that comes from the server but that does not get parsed

Comment: No need to escape your date separators `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` and make sure to set the timeZone to UTC and your locale to `"en_US_POSIX"`

Comment: Your date format it is missing the timezone

Comment: @Rob I was about to check that also

Comment: Thank's guys, but i tried with timeZone and locale, but unfortunately with no success((

Comment: interesting, with the text you included it works for me

Comment: Anton, unrelated to the question at hand, but I'd suggest you retire SwiftyJSON. There's no need for it if you're going to use `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: @LeoDabus - "date you posted in your screen shot it is totally different from the one you are showing now" ... I'm not sure if I follow you.

Comment: @AntonZhevchenko check updated answer, you have a simple typo in your text `print(object[0]["datareg"].dateTime)` should be `print(object[0]["datereg"].dateTime)`

Comment: so just change `"datareg"` to `"datereg"` and you should be good to go

Comment: @Rob actually the date it is not from the JSON

Comment: thank's Milan you are right! but i preferable want to use JSONDecoder as it is native for swift))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your text:

```
print(object[0]["datareg"].dateTime)
```

should be

```
print(object[0]["datereg"].dateTime)
```

Comment: That would be a reason to close as off-topic (simple typographical error)

Comment: I posted the all function, so that anyone who interested to help could use to reproduce my problem)

Comment: @AntonZhevchenko is this not the cause of your problem?

Comment: Yes using SwiftyJSON))

Comment: Yes you solved my problem)) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to parsing a JSON.

**Before Swift 4**

Before Swift 4 you could only use JSONSerialization Class (like in your example). This method return a Any object that can be cast in a Dictionary (the type depends on the data you are receiving).

For example:

```
if let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Dictionary<String,String>{
   do some stuff...
}
```

If you have multiple kind of data you should use this casting:

```
if let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Dictionary<String,Any?>{
       do some stuff...
}
```

Then you can access to all the data in the dictionary by the key and manage the data (if you use Any remember to cast in the correct data before using them).

Here some documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization

**After Swift 4**

With Swift 4 a new class was introduced: JSONEncoder and JSONDecoder. It's amazing, because you can create your model, parsing the json and you'll get an object with all the fields already filled. Pay attention that your model MUST implements the protocol Codable (or Encodable and Decodable). If your model doesn't implements the protocol you'll get an error.

Here an example:

This is my model:

```
class myClass: Codable{
    var Id: Int
    var Identifier: String
    var Alias: String
    var Revision: Int
    var Title: String
}
```

And this is the code for the parsing:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let myClass = try! decoder.decode(Questionario.self, from: (json?.data(using: .utf8))!)
```

Now my variable "myClass" already contains all the field filled with the data in the json.

Here some documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: Thank's a lot , but i was testing JSONSerializator and JSONDecoder and also tried SwiftyJSON as you see above, and in every case i see that with data from server "datareg" field coming with date, but after parsing i receive nil(

Comment: Can you show me the dataString when you download it? You have the problem only in that field?